# Can China or the IAEA end Israel's nuclear program?

Tags: china, israel, nuclear-weapons

> Li said China has been actively supporting the region's efforts to
> establish a Middle East zone free of nuclear weapons and other WMDs.
>
> Li urged Israel to accede to the treaty on the non-proliferation of
> nuclear weapons (NPT) as a non-nuclear weapon state "as soon as
> possible" and to place all its nuclear facilities under the
> comprehensive safeguards of the IAEA.
>
> He called on relevant countries in the region and nuclear-weapon
> states to shoulder their responsibilities and participate in the
> process of establishing a Middle East zone free of nuclear weapons and
> other WMDs within the framework of the United Nations.

https://english.news.cn/20231123/41d409dcdaa74ae8823451428a6700cb/c.html

> The State of Israel is widely believed to possess nuclear weapons.
> Estimates of Israel's stockpile range between 80 and 400 nuclear
> warheads,[2][5][6][7][8][9] and the country is believed to possess the
> ability to deliver them in several methods, including by aircraft, as
> submarine-launched cruise missiles, and via the Jericho series of
> intermediate to intercontinental range ballistic missiles.[18][19] Its
> first deliverable nuclear weapon is thought to have been completed in
> late 1966 or early 1967; which would make it the sixth country in the
> world to have developed them.[2][20][21]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_weapons_and_Israel

Can China or the IAEA end Israel's nuclear program? Here, China seem to assume that Israel doesn't have any nuclear weapon, but here it seems that China is also making a veiled threat against Israel. Does China really have any power to end Israel nuclear program?

Comment: Pie in the sky.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be fair, China is only asking, not so much threatening.  Call it a pious bit of theater that few probably paid any attention to `*`

It is also worthwhile looking at the context where it was made:

> "The Middle East should not be threatened by nuclear weapons. This is the common call from countries in the region," Li Song, China's permanent representative to the International Atomic Energy Agency (IAEA), told a meeting of the agency's board of governors on Wednesday.

So basically you have a *Chinese NPT representative* telling an *internal NPT meeting* that Israel should follow the NPT.  What next?  A Tuvalu IPCC (UN climate change panel) staffer criticizing US and Chinese coal mining?  Stop the presses!

---

No. [Key Roles | IAEA](https://www.iaea.org/newscenter/focus/npt/key-roles)

> NPT Article III: The IAEA administers international safeguards to verify that non-nuclear weapon **States party to the NPT** fulfill the non-proliferation commitment they have made, "with a view to preventing diversion of nuclear energy from peaceful uses to nuclear weapons or other nuclear explosive devices."

[Israel has **not** signed the NPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_on_the_Non-Proliferation_of_Nuclear_Weapons#Non-parties) and I don't see how China can compel them to:

- This is generally true, short of sanctions or force of arms - how do you **force** a state to sign a treaty?
- Israel pretends not to have them, has a fair bit of Western backing in any case and can, reasonably, claim that Iran's nuclear program precludes denuclearization.  While it is popular to beat on Israel for its nukes, the Palestinian issue is politically a lot more sensitive.  Despite not being given to conspirational thinking, some of Iran's Arab neighbors might even not be entirely averse to an Israeli dissuasion force.
- **IF** Israel gave up its nukes, as asked - which is **very** unlikely - it stands to reason that they would be used as a bargaining chip in some larger negotiations (I don't have a clue what would be enticing enough however).  Giving them up for nothing in return, as in this case, makes no sense at all, as China surely knows.
- China's lackluster efforts with regards to limiting North Korea's nuclear programs makes them look less than entirely serious here.  China is posturing for the developing countries.  And, really, Israel and China are not even on such bad terms.

Makes for good Chinese foreign policy PR tho ;-)

`*` [Google of `Li+Song+israel+iaea`](https://www.google.com/search?q=Li+Song+israel+iaea) comes up very nearly empty.